# Object List View Highlight Renderer with Composite Filters

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I'm trying to filter an object list view with a composite filter (i.e. multiple filter conditions) but the default highlight text renderer only renders the text of the first filter.

Is there a way to make it apply to all filters or better yet use multiple text renderers one for each filter?

I'm using control characters (&& and ||) to delimit search terms

Some C&P code to illustrate

```
public void Filter (string txt, MatchKind matchKind) {
     bool filterByAll;
     IEnumerable<string> terms = SplitSearchTerms(txt, out filterByAll);
     List<IModelFilter> modelFilters = new List<IModelFilter>();
     foreach (string term in terms) {
        IModelFilter filter;
        switch (matchKind) {
              case MatchKind.Contains:
              default:
                 filter = TextMatchFilter.Contains(_olv, term);
                 break;
              case MatchKind.Prefix:
                 filter = TextMatchFilter.Prefix(_olv, term);
                 break;
              case MatchKind.Regex:
                 filter = TextMatchFilter.Regex(_olv, term);
                 break;
           }
        modelFilters.Add(filter);
     }

     CompositeFilter compositeFilter;
     if (filterByAll) {
        compositeFilter = new CompositeAllFilter(modelFilters);
     } else {
        compositeFilter = new CompositeAnyFilter(modelFilters);
     }
     //Only highlights text from the first filter
     HighlightTextRenderer renderer = _olv.DefaultRenderer as HighlightTextRenderer;
     if (renderer != null) {
        SolidBrush brush = renderer.FillBrush as SolidBrush ?? new SolidBrush(Color.Transparent);
        if (brush.Color != Color.LightSeaGreen) {
           brush.Color = Color.LightSeaGreen;
           renderer.FillBrush = brush;
           _olv.DefaultRenderer = renderer;
        }
     } else {
        MessageBox.Show(@"Renderer is null!");
     }
     _olv.ModelFilter = compositeFilter;
  }
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Any luck finding a solution? Pretty old post, I know :)

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works for me. Multiple columns support still with highlighting support.

```
var filters = new List<IModelFilter>();
TextMatchFilter highlightingFilter = null;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text))
{
    var words = txtSearch.Text.Trim().Split(null);
    highlightingFilter = TextMatchFilter.Contains(ListView, words);
    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        var filter = TextMatchFilter.Contains(ListView, word);
        filters.Add(filter);
    }
}
var compositeFilter = new CompositeAllFilter(filters);

ListView.ModelFilter = highlightingFilter;
ListView.AdditionalFilter = compositeFilter;
ListView.DefaultRenderer = new HighlightTextRenderer(highlightingFilter);
```

Comment: Thank you!! So the DefaultRenderer is what highlights the text, by giving it all the terms you can have it highlight all of them. I'm unclear as to what the benefit of using both the ModelFilter and the AdditionalFilter is, can you highlight any reasons for that?

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea why this works, but for me it does :)